# How to have a sticky thead in a table

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, datatable

I want the thead not to move while scrolling in the table, i cant set the overflow auto on the tbody so how can i fix that?

I already tried to do the style="overflow: auto; height: 650px;" on the tbody but it doesnt even work at all

```
<div class="row m-t-30">
    <div style="overflow: auto; height: 650px;" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="table-responsive m-b-40">
            <table id="productsTable" class="table table-borderless table-data3">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Klant</th>
                    <th>Werknemer</th>
                    <th>Datum</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($clients->getAllclients() as $client) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $client['client_name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $client['client_id'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $client['client_address'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td><button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="See" onclick="seeOrder(\'' . $client['client_id'] . '\')"><i style="font-size: 20px" class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i></button></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: sticky;` for table

```
table thead tr th {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
```

Below is the demo for sticky thead

```css
table thead tr th {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column2</th>
      <th>column3</th>
      <th>column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
      <td>td</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me the thead will just be white and doe not stick at the top

Comment: @BoVerzaal it would be helpful if you make a working snippet for the same

Comment: @BoVerzaal to make it work in your case, you need to set the overflow 1 level down in your structure https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BgxzOm

Comment: remove your css and replace it with this 
`table thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background: lightblue;
}` @BoVerzaal

Comment: @BoVerzaal Please accept my answer if it helped you